# How to get warnings for variable hiding in Java inheritance?

Tags: java

I encountered a bug in a Java program because I did not understand hiding with inheritance.

My bug came down to this:

```
class Animal {
    int numPaws = 4;
}

class Snake extends Animal {
    int numPaws = 0;
}

class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Snake s = new Snake();

        /* There two different copies of this variable,
           but no override warning as there would be with a method. */
        System.out.println(s.numPaws);
        System.out.println(((Animal)s).numPaws);
    }
}
```

Now I want to ask:

If I do this with methods, I get warning and told to use @Override decorator. Why do I get no warning with variables?

How do I check for this in future?

Also why does Java provide no warning system? Or, why does it allow it with variables?

Comment: AFAIK the Java compiler itself doesn't support that. If you're using a decent IDE like Eclipse, Idea etc. you can let it check that. On the command line there are tools like PMD or checkstyle although I don't know what they support.

Comment: Instance variables aren't polymorphic like methods are.

Comment: @Thomas How to tell Eclipse to check this?

Comment: @torno have a look at Preferences->Java->Compiler->Errors/Warnings and on that page under "Name shadowing and conflicts".

Comment: You are right. But when declaring both variables as private, there is no warning.

Comment: The accepted good practices in Java are to hide the fields behind getters and setters, which can be overridden, if needed. In part because of this behavior. In a more extreme form, there should be an interface and the descendants have to implement it. That wild avoid such a big at the cost of having more verbose definition

Comment: @torno. Private variables exist only at the specific class. Or is ok to have the same name as they are not shared. For protected, public, and package scope, a warning is a good idea...